# How to access static js files in EJS?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have folder structure like

```
--project
----public
------flowplayer
----views
```

I want to access files inside js folder from the ejs file inside views. I tried like this but did not work

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

From EJS I am accessing file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js"></script>
```

But I am getting error like

```
http://localhost:3000/connect/125468/test/48B1527B237BB/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js
```

Thanks

Comment: n which endpoint you are using to render ejs template?

Comment: I am trying to render from a different file in project folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by giving the path for the required js file in ejs as '/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js' instead of '../public/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.13.min.js'